# Twitter api 'data-tweet-limit'-attribute doesnt work

Tags: twitter

I am trying to embed tweets on my web site and I want to limit it to 6 tweets, but the attribute `data-tweet-limit`, that twitter (X) recommend doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="350" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" data-chrome="transparent" href="https://twitter.com/FriendsTV?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-tweet-limit="6"> 
    Tweets by FriendsTV
</a> 
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have tried several different things, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

X appears to not currently support the data-tweet-limit attribute

This may change in the future since it's still listed in its documentation, but there are many other threads experiencing the same issue over the past six months.